# How to disable autocomplete of an input text after creating own autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have a problem and I can't figure how to solve it.

After registering, the user is redirected to a page and they must enter their city, and then a city list corresponding to what they are writing is displayed, and I have done this by creating my own autocomplete.

The problem, however, is that the browser now does not respect the `autocomplete="false"` of `autocomplete="off"`.

Note that there is no password field. What should I do ?

A turn-around is that if I set `autocomplete="new-password"` then there is no autocomplete in the browser.

Should I use it, even if it's not a password?

> I would like to have no autocomplete on all the browsers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : autocomplete="__away"

Comment: Thanks for your help ! 
autocomplete="__away" seems to work ! But is that for all browser ? I try in Google Chrome !!!
Thanks a lot !

Comment: On my editor, i receive a warning for __away : Undefined attribute value (__away) ????

Answer (score 0):

you should put autocomplete="off" both on the form, AND on the input element itself. That way you cover all the nonstandardness of browsers.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for you help! It doen't work..... i add autocomplete="off" to the form tag and to my input... and when i click on my imput(gotfocus) i have all my old value that appear above the field...
Do you have another idea ?